# evm_mine in parity dev chain. Fast forward time in Development Chain

Tags: truffle, parity, testing

Everybody loves `testrpc`, except me.
So, I like to write unit test against real parity dev chain node.
The question is how to fast forward timestamp(create new blocks) ?

```
function advanceBlock() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    web3.currentProvider.sendAsync({
      jsonrpc: '2.0',
      method: 'evm_mine',
      id: Date.now(),
    }, (err, res) => {
      return err ? reject(err) : resolve(res)
    })
  })
}
```

Need to create similar way for 
`parity --chain dev`

the only way that I could find right now is by overwriting `now` variable in MockedContract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.15;

import '../../contracts/WhitelistedCappedCrowdsale.sol';
contract WhitelistedCappedCrowdsaleMock is WhitelistedCappedCrowdsale {
    uint64 public time = now;

    function getTime() public contstant returns(uint64) {
       return time;
    }

    function setTime(uint64 _time) public {
        time = _time;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you could just point a [miner to your dev chain](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/25239/mine-blocks-in-parity-development-chain/25388#25388) to create new blocks fast.