# Mine blocks in Parity development chain?

Tags: parity

Using the `dev` [private development chain](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/Private-development-chain) in Parity works well for testing out generic contract interactions, since transactions are mined instantly in a pretty slick manner. But, I'm trying to test a contract interaction that waits a number of blocks (time-locked deposits).

The only way I can see to advance blocks in the `dev` chain is to just send ether transactions back and forth between the testnet accounts. But that's rather tedious to try and get a bunch of blocks added to the chain.

Is there a way to add several empty blocks to the Parity `dev` chain all at once, or do I have to make a bunch of manual transactions to simulate the blockchain growing?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question but if you're trying to test your contract, you might like to consider using pyethereum for testing. You can simulate a blockchain in memory, mine blocks, mess with timestamps etc and run your tests against the simulated blockchain in all the different states you need to cover.

Answer (score 2):

Just small hint you can automate this manual process of creating blocks. Key is to use `--unlock` and `--password` options when running parity so you have one unlocked account.

Then create simple script that will transfer some eth from unlocked account every x seconds.

For example in js its something like this

```
const Web3 = require("web3");
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));

const src = "0x123...";
const dest = "0x456...";

setInterval( () => {
  web3.eth.sendTransaction({from:src, to:dest, value: web3.toWei(1, "ether")});
}, 12000);
```

Answer (score 0):

The development chain accepts any block you give it.

Just get `ethminer` and run it on CPU and it should create valid blocks for your development chain. You might have to run Parity with the `--author` flag to enable mining though.